# DateTime.TryParse converts decimal to datetime

Tags: c#, datetime, tryparse

The following line of code return true (which it should not)....and convert 1.0228 into datetime...

```
DateTime.TryParse(1.0228,out temporaryDateTimeValue)
```

Somebody please help me.

Comment: Really? It shows up as a compile error for me because TryParse needs a string. Are you sure you're using `System.DateTime`?

Comment: What are you getting in the temporaryDateTimeValue after the call?

Comment: `1.0228` is no decimal, it's a double.

Comment: What implementation of the .NET platform are you using? `DateTime.TryParse()` is only supposed to have two overloads, and neither of those take a `double` as their first argument.

Comment: And your code doesn't compile `The best overloaded method match for 'System.DateTime.TryParse(string, out System.DateTime)' has some invalid arguments
  - Argument 1: cannot convert from 'double' to 'string'` since `double` isn't implicitly convertible to `string`. Please post a program that reproduces the problem.

Comment: In .Net 4, DateTime.TryParse takes a string, I put in that line of code above and it will not compile. (string s, Out DateTime).  1.0228 is not a string.

Comment: @Anish, you might have an extension method that implements `DateTime.TryParse(double, out DateTime)` in scope. How many overloads does Intellisense list for `TryParse()`?

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi: Not with a capitalized `DateTime` he does not (assuming he also has a `using System;` declaration).

Comment: @Jason, whoops, you were right, I was being silly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> The following line of code return true (which it should not)....and convert 1.0228 into datetime...

```
DateTime.TryParse(1.0228,out temporaryDateTimeValue)
```

This will not compile.

However, if you wrap it in quotes (and clean it up a little bit),

```
bool success = DateTime.TryParse("1.0228", out temporaryDateTimeValue);
```

then, yes, you will get `true` back. You need to read the documentation to understand why, but basically, there are many different ways to format dates and you stumbled on one (maybe `M.yyyy`?).

If you don't want it to parse, may I suggest

```
bool success = DateTime.TryParseExact(
                   "1.0228",
                   "yyyyMMdd", 
                   CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                   DateTimeStyles.None,
                   out temporaryDateTimeValue
               );
```

Then `success` is `false`.

I note from the remarks in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1.aspx):

> The string `s` is parsed using formatting information in the current `DateTimeFormatInfo` object, which is supplied implicitly by the current thread culture.
>
> This method tries to ignore unrecognized data, if possible, and fills in missing month, day, and year information with the current date. If s contains only a date and no time, this method assumes the time is 12:00 midnight. Any leading, inner, or trailing white space character in s is ignored. The date and time can be bracketed with a pair of leading and trailing NUMBER SIGN characters ('#', U+0023), and can be trailed with one or more NULL characters (U+0000).
>
> Because the `DateTime.TryParse(String, DateTime)` method tries to parse the `string` representation of a date and time using the formatting rules of the current culture, trying to parse a particular `string` across different cultures can either fail or return different results. If a specific date and time format will be parsed across different locales, use the `DateTime.TryParse(String, IFormatProvider, DateTimeStyles, DateTime)` method or one of the overloads of the `TryParseExact` method and provide a format specifier.

Basically, `TryParse` "tries" very hard to parse the string you give it (although the "`Try`" really refers to the fact that the method returns a bool for success/failure indication).

Comment: If I use other override of DateTime.TryParse..with cultural info...what is the cultural info and datetimestyle i need to give?

Answer (score 4):

No, that code doesn't return true - it doesn't even compile:

```
using System;

class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DateTime dt;
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.TryParse(1.0228, out dt));
    }
}
```

Error:

```
Test.cs(9,27): error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for
        'System.DateTime.TryParse(string, out System.DateTime)' has some invalid
        arguments
Test.cs(9,45): error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'double' to
        'string'
```

---

If you change it to "1.0228" it *does* return true, yes. It looks like it's using a format of "M.yyyy", which is no doubt valid for some cultures... and highlights why it's a bad idea to use `DateTime.TryParse` in my view. If you've got a specific format (or set of formats) in mind, you should use [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx) instead so you can specify the format.

I usually find it's a good idea to specify the exact format, and I *usually* also specify `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` unless the date is coming directly from the user (which is rare, in my experience).

Comment: I guess it might return `January 1st, 228 A.D.` since some cultures use a dot as the date separator.

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi: Yup, that seems to be the date it's coming up with. I really hate the default "we'll just try to parse it in hundreds of ways" approach of DateTime.TryParse, personally.

Comment: It's apparently matching M.yyyy

Comment: @Jon, well, that strategy *does* improve code coverage in unit tests ;)